# Using the Google API Client library in an iOS Swift project with a Google Cloud Endpoints client

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-storage, google-client

I have a Podfile as follows:

```
platform :ios, '8.3'

use_frameworks!

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.1.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.1.0'
pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk', '~> 1.7.1'
pod 'FXForms', '~>1.2.12'
pod 'JGProgressHUD', '~>1.2.6'
pod 'Google-API-Client', '~> 1.0.422'
pod 'XCGLogger','~> 2.0'
pod 'PulsingHalo'
pod 'NYXImagesKit','~> 2.3.0'
```

and a bridging header as follows:

```
#import <GoogleOpenSource/GTMOAuth2Authentication.h>

#import <GooglePlus/GPPSignIn.h>
#import <GooglePlus/GPPSignInButton.h>
#import <GooglePlus/GPPURLHandler.h>

#import "GTLApi.h"

#import <Google-API-Client/GTLStorage.h>
```

`GTLApi.h` in the above is a generated client for a Google Cloud Endpoints API. On building, the pods build OK but the bridging header doesn't. It fails with hundreds of compilation errors for things being defined twice.

How is the Google-API-Client supposed to co-exist with a Cloud Endpoints API client? Both of them import `GTLObject.h`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Google APIs Client Library for Objective C](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client) has now been replaced with the [Google APIs Client Library for REST](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest), which uses the GTLR prefix instead of GTL (eg. GTLRObject.h) so as not to clash, so it's recommended to use the newer library instead.

Comment: can you please help me i need any sample for this new library as google still have old sample available. Spent two days already.